# Share another users picture in my gallery

Tags: image, drupal, share

> I want to share another user gallery picture in such a way that on the click of share the image should be stored in my image Gallery.adding to this i should also be provided with an option of in which gallery i want to store(add) this picture depending on the list of galleries i have in my profile.
>   I am Using Drupal.
>   How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for IMCE module: http://drupal.org/project/imce